# ObjC is a "run-time language"?

Tags: objective-c, terminology

Can any one tell me why Objective-C is called a "run-time language"

Comment: I don't think you are understanding it correctly. Would you add the original reference where you read this statement?

Comment: Where did you see it called that?

Comment: We're not here to answer questions that can be solved in 2 minutes by using Google...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Technically, it's not a runtime language-- it is, however, a runtime *oriented* language.

> Objective-C is a runtime oriented language, which means that when it's possible it defers 
>   decisions about what will actually be executed from compile & link time to when it's 
>   actually executing on the runtime.

From [here](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2010/01/understanding-objective-c-runtime.html).

Comment: Objective-C is a very dynamic language. Its dynamism frees a program from compile-time and link-time constraints and shifts much of the responsibility for symbol resolution to runtime, when the user is in control. Objective-C is more dynamic than other programming languages because its dynamism springs from three sources:
·         Dynamic typing—determining the class of an object at runtime
·         Dynamic binding—determining the method to invoke at runtime
·         Dynamic loading—adding new modules to a program at runtime